# Angular autocomplete with json response data not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the autocomplete to work for angular material and autofill by names. I have the response object with the data, but when I assign it to `this.options = res["posts"].name;`
I get undefined. this.options If I change `this.options = res["posts"];` then the autocomplete shows two [Object object].  Which makes sense because my response only returns two documents from mongodb. So the response is there, but I can't get it to assign to the autocomplete properly.

Is the only way to for loop and put each value in the options[]? I was concerned about performance if theres a lot of users if I did that
`this.options = res["posts"][i].name;`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { MessagingService } from './messaging.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-messaging',
  templateUrl: './messaging.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messaging.component.css']
})
export class MessagingComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: any = [];
  constructor(private messagingService: MessagingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.messagingService.getUsers().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.options = res["posts"].name;
      console.log(this.options);

    });

  }
```

Comment: I think you have to map the names, since you're expecting an array, like:

`this.options = res.posts.map(({ name }) => name);`